# time series anomally detection - Deep learning approach

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders, anomaly-detection

I am familiar with deeplearning and autoencoders. i was wondering whether there is an algorithm, using autoencoders, for anomaly detection. In general, is there a deeplearning approach for anomaly detection of time series?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details? What kind of anomaly are you searching for? quantity of data? ???

Comment: Every information about my time series really helps me. I know that by autoencoders we can obtain an abstract representation of our data, i was wondering whether this abstract representation is possible for time series? Furthermore, detecting outliers in the time series would be really helpful.

Comment: OK, but tell **us** some more about your timeseries!

Comment: Each one of them is a signal over 4 seconds.

Comment: What kind of signal? How many of them? How densely sampled?

Comment: i have 1000 records of signals, each of them has 100 time points. i want to see whether there is an abstract representation of my signal or not? consider my signal as a voice sound.